# How to offset the error in calculating cartesian coordinates from polar coordinates

Tags: python, math, pygame, coordinates, pow

I'm currently trying to develop a to-scale model of the universe using pygame. At the moment, when I'm calculating the x, y positions of the planets w.r.t. the sun, the planets are slowly falling towards the sun, despite only using equations for position based on the distance and angle of the planet (no force).

Here is the code snippet for calculating distance from a given star currently:

```
def d_obj(self, reference):

    x_diff_sq = pow(self.x - reference.pos[0], 2)
    y_diff_sq = pow(self.y - reference.pos[1], 2)
    return pow(x_diff_sq + y_diff_sq, 0.5)
```

And then I pass what this function returns into the next function for calculating the position

```
def move(self, d):
    self.theta += self.d_theta
    self.x = int(d * math.cos(self.theta)) + total_d/2
    self.y = int(d * math.sin(self.theta)) + total_d/2
```

total_d/2 is a co-ordinate offset and self.d_theta is the rotational period for the given planet.

Each planet has its initial position hard coded and I'm using this to calculate the difference between initial distance and current distance for all of the planets, every tick it is apparent that the planet moves about 1km towards the sun. Is there any way I can attempt to offset this?

I understand that in the scale of things where I'm drawing things in terms of millions of km, I'm just curious what part of these equations is causing the error. I've tried using the '**' operator over pow and after some research online found that pow is better used for powers involving floats.

Should also mention that all calculations are in kilometers, then before drawing, the planets radius and x, y are mapped to the screen from a set distance that is currently around 4 AU.

Comment: Try math.hypot, you'll lose a ton of precision with numbers that big squaring them naively.

Comment: @gct I checked out the hypot docs and it looks like it does the same as what mine is doing but multiplies the numbers as opposed to raising them to an exponent. Is there a difference in doing this?

Comment: Why are you calculating Cartesian coordinates at all? You can "solve" your system in polar, and do the Cartesian calculation only for drawing.

Comment: @rhyso98 hypot takes care to be numerically stable for large and small numbers

Comment: Try `round` instead of `int`

Comment: @Stratubas thats what this function is for. d_theta is calculated and isn't influenced by the x, y coords and then this move function is applied just before drawing to utilise the new theta. I think the system is already solved in a polar form so I'm confused by your point.

Comment: @gct I tried using hypot alongside the current method and while they produced very slightly different results, they both still tended towards (0, 0)

Comment: @Rabbid76 thanks I'll try now

Comment: @Rabbid76 round actually helped alot, there's still the slight decline but its much less noticeable now thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to move your planets in circles, right?

In your code, you

1. Use x and y to calculate distance,
2. Use delta_theta to calculate new theta,
3. Use new theta and distance to calculate new x and y.

You don't have to do all that. Instead, you can keep a hardcoded distance and just

1. Use delta_theta to calculate new theta,
2. Use new theta and (known) distance to calculate x and y for drawing.

Then your distance will not drift at all.

---

Side note: If you're planning to keep the planets moving for long times, make sure you keep your theta between 0 and 2*pi, or rounding errors will start kicking in and your theta accuracy will deteriorate.

---

You're thinking this will make adding moons and asteroids difficult.

Not really!

You can do the same for moons, by noting which planet they belong to, the distance to that planet, delta_theta and initial theta (based on their parent planet).

If you want to start doing ellipses instead of circles, you can change your calculations (use convenient constant [orbital elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_elements) instead of distance and delta_theta, which will not be constant anymore) to apply [Kepler's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion).

You can also add asteroids later. You can keep the Cartesian positions and velocities of the asteroids, and calculate their motion separately, after calculating the motion of all the "trivially" moving objects.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean. I was doing this intitially but then I realised that if i wanted to do some sort of moon system or, eventually asteroids, I would have to hardcode the distance for each of these interactions. I'll also put a check in that keeps theta under 2PI.

Comment: Thanks so much! I hadn't really thought about it like that. I was hoping to implement some of Kepler's laws later, thanks for the insight on that. Eventually after figuring out the rest of the small mechanics such as this one, I was hoping to implement a proper gravity/force system so all interstellar objects could interact with one another hence the reason for objects being able to interact with one another through iteration but I guess it makes sense to leave the planets as fixed orbits and allow things like asteroids to have true orbits.